# Barleywine fermentation is slow. How can I speed it up?

Tags: beer, fermentation, barleywine

My barley wine has been brewing for two weeks it should have be 1108 after 4-6 days its currently still fermenting at 1025.Its been at a constant temp of 22 degrees. However when yeast was added it was a bit to warm at 28 degrees is there anything I can do to speed up the fermentation process?

Answer (score 3):

Rousing the yeast and fermenting at warmer temperatures will speed fermentation. However, particularly with a barley wine -- where there are a lot of sugars present -- it can take more than a week for fermentation complete.  If the gravity continues to go down, my advice is to leave it alone.  If the gravity stops changing over the course of several days, and it is still significantly higher than your expected finishing gravity, you may want to pitch more yeast.  If you do, pay attention to the alcohol tolerance of the strain you use.  For this purpose, brewers will often use champaign yeast, because of its high alcohol tolerance. (15-17 percent)  Although champaign yeast produces a very dry, clean taste, the first yeast strain should have contributed its flavor already.

As an aside, you seem to be in a hurry.  Barleywine is a style that rewards patience.  I have a barley wine from Sun King here in Indianapolis that is two years old and is only just now reaching its prime.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a BW to finish at too low a final gravity.  The 1.025 it's at right now is just about perfect.  But it's really hard to say what's going on without knowing your recipe, techniques,and OG.